# Density map of lines based on points on a half sphere

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, heatmap

I am running a simulation that outputs the alt and az poistion of various objects for each timestep. I am able to plot them as lines, but i am running into two issues trying to make a density plot out of them.

1. it seems the densityplot is based on the points and not on the lines
2. the area on the half sphere is not equal area

maybe i have to transform the data from alt/az to x,y?

data can be found [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/9dbd6e7a)

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math


df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

print(df)

starlink_name = df.loc[:,'Name']
starlink_alt = df.loc[:,'starlink_alt']
starlink_az = df.loc[:,'starlink_az']

name = starlink_name.values
alt = starlink_alt.values
az = starlink_az.values
print(name)
print(df['Name'].nunique())
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

for name, df_name in df.groupby('Name'):
    print(name)

df_grouped = df.groupby('Name')



list_of_names = list(df_grouped.groups)
#########################################################################################
#LinePlot
#########################################################################################
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], polar=True)
# ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_rlim(90, 60, 1)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 91, 15))
ax.set_rlim(bottom=90, top=0)

def legend_without_duplicate_labels(ax):
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    unique = [(h, l) for i, (h, l) in enumerate(zip(handles, labels)) if l not in labels[:i]]
    ax.legend(*zip(*unique),loc= 'upper right')


    ax.plot(np.deg2rad(df2['starlink_az']), df2['starlink_alt'], linestyle='solid', marker='.',linewidth=0.5, markersize=0.1 )
legend_without_duplicate_labels(ax)
plt.show()

#########################################################################################
#DensityPlot
#########################################################################################
# define binning
rbins = np.linspace(0,90, 45)
abins = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 360)

#calculate histogram
hist, _, _ = np.histogram2d(np.deg2rad(az), alt, bins=(abins, rbins))
A, R = np.meshgrid(abins, rbins)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="polar"))

# ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_rlim(90, 0, 1)
# Note: you must set the end of arange to be slightly larger than 90 or it won't include 90
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 91, 15))
ax.set_rlim(bottom=90, top=0)

pc = ax.pcolormesh(A, R, hist.T, cmap="jet")
fig.colorbar(pc)

plt.show()```
````

Comment: How do you want the density to be computed? The number of lines that go through each bin?

Comment: yes exactly! basically the lines are satellite trails and i would like to compute the number of trails per bin.

Comment: Hmmm, some sort of raytracing histogram but in polar coordinates. Doesn’t exactly sound easy. Just making sure, the histogram should be proportional to the number of rays and not the length of ray per bin, right?

Comment: In fact raytracing is computing the intersection of lines fundamentally, of a ray on one side and the bin edges on the other side. Here it’s intersections between rays and concentric circles of various sizes.

Comment: There’s a number of nice formulas [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1999/AGraphHCI/SMAG/node2.html), I’ll try to find some time to go through it in the upcoming week if noone else gets around to it.

Comment: i try to do a different approch as in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12335.pdf), i simulate TLEs for future sat constellations.  the idea is to get the finestructure of the shells.

Comment: yes, i just like to get the traildensity per bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I’ve gotten the most part done.

As said in comments, we want to compute the intersection of lines with bins in polar coordinates. We could try solving intersections with circles, i.e. for 2 points B solve `(1 - t) * A + t * B = r²` for all desired `r`. This solution goes for the other way, computing the intersection of lines with the “spokes” that define the bin edges.

I’ll just give you a thoroughly commented code, it should be self-explanatory:

```
# params: bin sizes
rmax = 90
rbin = rmax / 45
abin = 2 * np.pi / 360

# load data
df = pd.read_csv('9dbd6e7a.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
df['Satellite'] = df['Name'].str.split('*', 1, expand=True)[0]

# Compute both coordinate systems of all points
points = pd.concat(axis='columns', objs={
    # Radians all the way
    'angle': df['starlink_az'].transform(np.deg2rad),
    # NB. we flip coordinates to have 0 at the center
    'dist': rmax - df['starlink_alt'],
})
points['x'] = points['dist'] * points['angle'].transform(np.cos)
points['y'] = points['dist'] * points['angle'].transform(np.sin)

# Compute segments here as pairs of points
segments = pd.concat(axis='columns', objs=[
    points.add_suffix('_a'),
    # .groupby() is optional, allows to skip segments between consecutive points of different origins
    points.add_suffix('_b').groupby(df['Satellite']).shift(-1),
    df['Satellite'],
]).dropna()

# Compute segment length and orthogonal vector
segments['dx'] = segments['x_b'] - segments['x_a']
segments['dy'] = segments['y_b'] - segments['y_a']
segments['length'] = (segments['dx'] ** 2 + segments['dy'] ** 2).transform(np.sqrt)
segments[['x_u', 'y_u']] = segments[['dy', 'dx']].mul({'dy': -1, 'dx': 1}).div(segments['length'], axis='index')

# From vector and one point, we get the angle and distance for polar formulation of line
segments['dist_p'] = (segments[['x_u', 'y_u']] * segments[['x_a', 'y_a']].values).sum(axis='columns')
segments[['x_u', 'y_u', 'dist_p']] = segments[['x_u', 'y_u', 'dist_p']].mul(segments['dist_p'].lt(0).map({True: -1, False: 1}), axis='index')
segments['angle_p'] = np.arctan2(segments['y_u'], segments['x_u'])

# True iff the intercept is in the segment, i.e. between A and B on the line
segments['in'] = segments['dist_p'].lt(segments['dist_a']) & segments['dist_p'].lt(segments['dist_b'])

segments['d_angle'] = (segments['angle_b'] - segments['angle_a']).transform(lambda s: s + (s.lt(-np.pi) * 2. - s.gt(np.pi) * 2.) * np.pi)
angle_rem = segments['angle_a'] % abin

# Generate angles of all line intersections with spokes
steps = pd.concat(axis='columns', objs={
    'angle_a': segments['angle_a'],
    'angle_b': segments['angle_a'] + segments['d_angle'], # Ensure the bound is in the right direction even if we had to wrap
    'start': segments['angle_a'] - segments['angle_a'] % abin + segments['d_angle'].gt(0) * abin,
    'end': segments['angle_a'] + segments['d_angle'] - segments['angle_b'] % abin + segments['d_angle'].lt(0) * abin, # no rounding needed at the end
    'step': segments['d_angle'].transform(np.sign) * abin,
}).agg(lambda s: [s['angle_a'], *np.arange(s['start'], s['end'], s['step']), s['angle_b']], axis='columns')
steps = steps.explode().infer_objects().to_frame('angle')

# Use polar line formulation to compute the distances at each bin edge
steps['dist'] = segments['dist_p'].reindex_like(steps) / (steps['angle'] - segments['angle_p'].reindex_like(steps)).transform(np.cos)

# This is our histogram, and the part that could be greatly improved, taking into account corner cases.
# We have interpolation at every bin edge « laterally » (along rotation) but we may skip some vertically (along distance)
hist = pd.crosstab(steps['dist'] // rbin, steps['angle'] // abin).reindex(index=np.arange(45), columns=np.arange(360)).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Now it can be perfected, but here’s the result it gives:

[image]

With the following code to plot:

```
# plot lines and heatmap side by side
fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8), subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'), ncols=2)

ticks = np.linspace(0, rmax, 7) # 6 ticks + last edge

# Plot unmodified data with 90 close to center and 0 outside, for verification
ax.plot(df['starlink_az'].transform(np.deg2rad), df['starlink_alt'], linestyle='solid', linewidth=.1)
ax.set_rlim(rmax, 0)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')

# Plot histogram data with 0 close to center and 90 at outside
grid = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi + abin / 2, abin), np.arange(0, 90 + rbin / 2, rbin))
pc = bx.pcolormesh(*grid, hist, cmap="jet")

bx.set_rlim(0, rmax)
bx.set_yticks(ticks)
# Invert tick display as we inverted values: 0 outside, 90 in the center
bx.set_yticklabels(ticks[::-1])
bx.set_theta_zero_location('N')

fig.colorbar(pc)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you very much it is what i was looking for!, just a quick question: there seems to be some kind of artefact from the center to the edge at 0°. do you have an idea why?

Comment: ````df['Satellite'] = df['Name'].str.split('*', 1, expand=True)[0]
```` i think that lines has an error , there can be multiple sats with the same name that way! when i remove the split part i geth an error : ValueError: arange: cannot compute length . i will try to fix it.

Comment: Hmm you’re right about the artifact @Taiko but I’m not sure what it is